# Referring subtitle of a slide in order to format, using VBA PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

[image: slide containing title and subtitle]I am trying to set the position and formatting of title, subtitle in the slide. I tried to change the position, font type of title and subtitle present in all slides using the following code. It works on title but there are no changes for subtitle position, font type. How can we get reference of subtitle to work on its position, font size etc.

```
  Sub Titles()
  Dim osld As Slide, oshp As Shape
    For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
       For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
        If oshp.Type = msoPlaceholder Then

         If oshp.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderTitle Then
          With oshp
            .Top = 5
            .Left = 5
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 24
          End With

         ElseIf oshp.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderSubtitle Then 
          With oshp
            .Top = 10
            .Left = 10
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 18
          End With

        End If


   End If

   Next oshp
 Next osld
 End Sub
```

Comment: Are you certain that `oshp.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderSubtitle`? Can you put a breakpoint in code and ensure that condition is met?

Comment: It would be a better practice (and faster) to set the positions of these elements on the slide master and layouts, then to reset the slides. With your current code, if someone inserts a new slide or resets an existing one, the placeholders will appear in the location specced in the corresponding layout. Then you'll have to rerun the macro.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is almost certainly that most corporate templates  use a placeholder with type ppPlaceholderBody rather than ppPlaceholderSubtitle for their subtitles. It’s not possible to add a ppPlaceholderSubtitle placeholder from the GUI, so template designers will usually just position an additional Body placeholder under the title.

The way we’ve dealt with identifying subtitles is:

1. Is the shape’s type a placeholder?
2. If yes, is it a Body placeholder?
3. If yes, is it within 50 pixels of both the expected Top and Left values for that placeholder, as it appears in the layout?

The third test is very important because users are always dragging, nudging, and repositioning template shapes. You have to include some level of wiggle when testing the position, otherwise you’ll miss lots of subtitles.

Comment: This is exactly what I am hustling with. The 'Subtitle' is named as " Text placeholder xx" in all slides, it is returning value 1 for both Title and Subtitle when I checked for the ppPlaceholderType.